# Time Module not working in Pycharm (I am using Python 3.8.5, Pycharm & Pygame)

Tags: python, time, module, pygame, pycharm

I am trying to write my first game using Python3 & Pygame in the Pycharm Community IDE. I am trying to make a simple Pong game :-D lol I am a beginner so please help me if you can.

When I run my code, I am getting the following error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/TechSlugz/PycharmProjects/Pong-Project/Pong1.py", line 7, in <module>
    clock = pygame.time.clock()
AttributeError: module 'pygame.time' has no attribute 'clock'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The code is just the basic set up for a game window, check it out

```
import pygame
import sys

# General Setup

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.clock()

# Setting Up The Main Window

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 960
screen = pygame.display.setmode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

while True:
    #handling input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

#Updating The Window

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

Can you notice anything that I am doing wrong to get this issue? None of my IDEs seem to recognise time as a pygame module but I am pretty damn sure it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock is a class, so you should use C instead of c.

`clock = pygame.time.Clock()`

and you have another problem, `setmode` is not an available function. You meant to write `set_mode`

The code that works fine for me:

```py
import pygame
import sys

# General Setup
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Setting Up The Main Window

screen_width = 1280
screen_height = 960
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")

while True:
    #handling input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.quit:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

#Updating The Window

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo sooo soo much dude! I have been really confused with this. C c makes all the difference aye! also the snake_case. Cheers again, worked like a Pycharm :-D pardon the sad noob puns :-P

Comment: It's okay! Have fun with Python and happy game developing! :)